# check if multiple select has option selected

Tags: jquery, multiple-select

I have the next select:

```
<select name="extra_especialidad[]" multiple="multiple">
```

For any reason the name is comming with brackets and I can't change or add anything to the element.

I am trying to check if the select has any option selected, I have tried this without success...

```
$("input[name=extra_especialidad\\[\\]]").length; //Gives me 0 always
$("input[name=extra_especialidad\\[\\]]").val().length; //gives me error
```

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the rendered markup that contains the `<select name="extra ...`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sd2n6/4/)):

```
$("select[name='extra_especialidad[]'] option:selected").length;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try a 'begins with' selector so you don't have to worry about the brackets.

`$("select[name^='extra_especialidad']").whatever()`

the `^=` in this case is matching names that start with `extra_especialidad`

Comment: for any reason it is returning 0 again, $("input[name^='extra_especialidad']").length